# What is the Java type for *short using JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

What is the Java type for *short using JNA

I have in my dll short and *short, so how can I call 
short -> int
*short -> int[]?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C `short` types map to Java `short` types.

C `short*` (pointer to a short) maps to Java using JNA's [`ShortByReference`](https://github.com/twall/jna/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/ShortByReference.html).

If you want to map pointers to arrays, [simply write the function in Java using arrays](https://github.com/twall/jna/#pointers), a function with signature

```
void foo(int *buf)
```

Maps in Java as

```
static void native foo(int[] buf);
```